# Datatable with angularJs shows no data error?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, datatable

I want to use datatable in angularjs. I have written directives and data table initializing and displaying rows in table first time.
When searching or filtering,it shows no data in table error message.

Directive code is

```
"use strict";
invoiceApp.directive('itemTable', function () {
return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/components/item/item_table.html',
        link: function (scope, table) {
            table.dataTable();

        }
    }
})
```

Template is,

```
<table my-table id="dt_basic" class="table table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
<thead>                         
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center" width="10">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-inline" id="slt_all">
        </th>
        <th data-class="expand">Name</th>
        <th data-hide="phone">Description</th>
        <th data-hide="phone">Unit</th>
        <th>Rate</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="checkbox-inline"></td>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.description}}</td>
        <td>{{item.unit}}</td>
        <td>AED {{item.rate}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Controller is,

```
    'use strict';
    invoiceApp.controller('itemController', ['$scope', 'ItemService', function ($scope, ItemService) {
$scope.items = //datas
        }]);
```

[image]
Why it happening ?

Comment: what module used for Data table ? or just jQuery Data table

Comment: yes..`jquery.dataTables.min.js`

Comment: thats weird, I faced similar problem, better use this angular Datatable http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withAjax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating new directive, simply add `datatable="` using this angular datatable module

HTML:

```
<table datatable="" class="row-border hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>Someone</td>
        <td>Youknow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>987</td>
        <td>Iamout</td>
        <td>Ofinspiration</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS :

```
angular.module('showcase', ['datatables']);
```

[More detail AngularJs Datatable](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/dataReloadWithAjax) and [Download](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/archive/master.zip)

Comment: `var invoiceApp = angular.module('invoiceApp', ['ngRoute','datatables']);`when I am declaring datatables,I getting angular error.which is `Error: [$injector:modulerr] .....`

Comment: you downloaded that file and included ?

Comment: Yes, problem with file.Now datatable working fine for static table.But when I am trying to load data from controller via service,it shows same error.

Answer (score 1):

Use "ng" inside your datatables="" directive..
Like this: datatables="ng" [click here to see an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KomIG.jpg)  This solves the problem in my case 
as i am using ng repeat to show the data in the table